# Identifier containing slash character '/' into the URI

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, restful-url

i am using **Express**, **mongodb** and **Angular** to create an application and one of my documents in MongoDB has an identifier as  *_id = '20161007/COMPANY-00/CL/01-01'*

I am trying to get the data from **Angular** via the **REstful** API using the identifier:

```
var _id = '20161007/COMPANY-00/CL/01-01';

this.$http.get('/api/datadays/' + _id)
      .then(response => {....}
```

But the result is:

> angular.js:11881 GET
>   http://localhost:9000/api/datadays/20161007/COMPANY-00/CL/01-01 404
>   (Not Found)

Are there some way to use slashes in the identifier to work with the restful API in node/express?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You should take a look at [Encode URI Component](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [Decode URI Component](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

Front-end code:

```
var _id = encodeURIComponent('20161007/COMPANY-00/CL/01-01');

this.$http.get('/api/datadays/' + _id)
      .then(response => {....}
```

Back-end code:

```
app.get('/api/datadays/:id', function(req, res) {
  let id = decodeURIComponent(req.params.id)
  ...
})
```